# How to not run javascript if IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a search field validation that I do not ran if the browser is IE8.

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#mini-search-form").submit(function() {
        var match =/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.exec(jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').val());
      if(!match){
        alert("Please enter valid search words.");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
</script>
```

I tried just surrounding that script with `<![if !IE 8]>` but Dreamweaver said that this was wrong.

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763688/disable-script-if-user-browsing-using-ie8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--[if !IE 8]-->
<script>
    ...
</script>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Selectively running code based off of the user's browser agent isn't best practice. Having said that below is crude solution:

```
if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8') == -1){
    jQuery("#mini-search-form").submit(function() {
        var match =/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.exec(jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').val());
        if(!match){
            alert("Please enter valid search words.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
});
```

*Feature Detection/Progressive Enhancement is a more preferred approach to cross-browser inconsistencies.*

Answer (score 0):

You may try this  but use [feature detection instead of browser detection](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/) (if not only related to `IE-8`)

```
<!--[if !(IE 8)]><!-->
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#mini-search-form").submit(function() {
            var match =/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.exec(jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').val());
            if(!match){
                alert("Please enter valid search words.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Read [About conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Any reason for the down vote would let me know the difference.