# Don't load a script in IE8 and below?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, conditional-comments

This question must be a duplicate, but I can't find the definitive answer on here.

How can I tell the browser not to load a script, if the browser is IE8 or below?

I know about targeting IE9 and above:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
 According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher<br />
<![endif]-->
```

but then the script does not load in non-IE browsers.

How can I say "load the script if not IE, or if IE and greater than IE8"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Conditional comment for 'Except IE8'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692129/conditional-comment-for-except-ie8/1692600#1692600)

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    // Your script here. This will only be loaded if IE version is greater than 8, OR any other browser.
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Should work?

Comment: @Mr_Green Why is that aproach better?

Comment: @JohanB sorry, you can go with any solution you like. at that time I was new to this :)

Comment: @Mr_Green In that case, can you remove your comment? Since it is a bit confusing now... Thanks

Comment: @PetervanKekem [Updated] Can also be done like this. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1692141/1577396)

Comment: Does this need to be in the head or can be anywhere in the body?