# How can I detect if my app runs under IE8 vs IE9 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, version-detection

I have a piece of functionality which needs to differ between IE8 and IE9 (IE9 uses a very nice library that is the main code path, but a slight minority of users of the app are still on IE8 which the library breaks under. So I need to gracefully degrade to less-nice library for them).

What is the best way to distinguish IE8 from IE9?

If possible, I'd like a version of the answer which treats IE9 with IE8 compatibility turned on as IE8; and one that treats it as IE9.

There's zero need to detect any other browsers or IE versions - this is for a locked down corporate environment so there's no risk of needing to detect beyond those 2.

Comment: Conditional comments.

Comment: [Browser detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Comment: @CrazyTrain - you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692129/conditional-comment-for-except-ie8

Comment: Feature detection is generally the better way to go.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - WOW! Impressive! But that seems a tad bit of an overkill when I only need to distinguish between IE8 and IE9?

Comment: @DVK Theres a version detection method in robert's javascript, you could just rip out the version detection pieces if you already know it'll be IE

Comment: @DVK: Yes. Don't use techniques that rely on the user-agent. That can be spoofed. Conditional comments can't.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - Good point in general, though I am not worried about spoofing. This is a bugfix for a broken-on-IE8 coporate internal use app, NOT fancy security code :)

Comment: @DVK: Alright, just saying in general that it's a more reliable method if all you need is IE detection.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Comments. There are some other alternatives but conditional comments are simple and functional. MSFT provides this information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx