# How to disable a jQuery script if IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, javascript

I have all my jQuery code for different elements of my website in one single file called scripts.js however there is one block of code I wish to disable if the user is using IE8. This is what I want to disable:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.parallax-block-1').parallax("50%", 0.1);
});
```

I've looked up everywhere and the only thing I found is to place an IF conditional comment like - `<!--[if !(IE 8)]><!-->` before `<script> </script>` in the html code but since I have everything in one single js file the IF statement would disable all the other scripts in it.

Hope my question makes sense.
Thank you all!

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: The latest I guess (jQuery 1.10.2)

Comment: You can use the conditional comment around a different `<script>` **before** your `<script>`, which sets a _flag_.

Comment: You mean the conditional comment that goes in the html code?

Comment: Do you use any programming language inside your page?

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean. I basically use html/css and javascrit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional comment for 'Except IE8'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692129/conditional-comment-for-except-ie8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<!--[if !(IE 8)]><!-->` to insert a class name into `<html>` tag, then inside your js file you can use that class name to specify whether enable the js function.
For example:
in html file:

```
 <!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]--> /* Rendered in IE8 browser */
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]--> /* Rendered in other browsers */
```

then in your JS file:

```
if ($("html.lt-ie9").length > 0) {
   //your functions or code that should work on all browsers except for IE8 goes here
}
```

Hope it helps.