# hide tracks in IE9 html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, jwplayer7

Here is my code:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && !jQuery.browser.version == 9) {

}else{
    var myVideoFrame = document.getElementById("myVideoFrame");
    myVideoFrame.textTracks[0].mode = "hidden";  
}
```

I am using JW Player but as I need my videos and video contents make indexable by search engines I created html5 video tag with source and track tags in it and implemented JW player setup javascript code on existing video id. In this case I needed to hide existing tracks cause I see double subtitles. Via code above it is hidden everywhere except IE 9 and gives me this error. Please see attached image. How can I hide tracks for IE9 ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [**this article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692129/conditional-comment-for-except-ie8) and added code written below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ie9 = false;
</script>
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <script>
        ie9 = true;
    </script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (ie9 == false) {
        var myVideoFrame = document.getElementById("myVideoFrame");
        myVideoFrame.textTracks[0].mode = "hidden";  
    }
</script>
```

Now this code works in every browser except IE9. So no error in console.